# Possible to disable URI on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, privacy

Apps can open other apps on iPhone using a URI scheme (e.g., open the Facebook app with `fb://`). Is there a way to disable this?

Comment: I’m fairly sure there isn’t, but I can’t prove it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to disable opening the apps instead of going to Safari, aside from deleting the app itself.